# jQuery Background-image Array Flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image

I've made controls that simulate a 3D environment. By default, each frame from an array will swap the background-image to create an animation.

My problem is that it seems the images don't load fast enough and creates a flickering effect, which I'd like to make the animation fluid between each frame. I thought of making the new images fades in and the old fade out on each new frames to reduce the flickering but, I'm not exactly sure how to use implement the fades on a background-image.

Also, I'm not exactly sure if it'll stop the flickering, so I was wondering if there's another solution.

Here's my code:

```js
var imagesArray = ['https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-1.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-3.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-5.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-7.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-9.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-11.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-13.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-15.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-17.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-19.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-21.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-23.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-25.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-27.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-29.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-31.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-33.jpg',
            'https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-35.jpg'];
        


        var ImageCounter = 0;


        
        //Turn frame backward
        $(".PreviousButton").click(function() {
            StartTurning = false;
            ImageCounter--;
            
            //Reset at end of loop.
            if (ImageCounter < 0) {
                ImageCounter = imagesArray.length - 1;
            }
            
            //Always update the image.
            $('.ImageDisplay').css({
                'background-image': 'url(' + imagesArray[ImageCounter] + ')'
            });
            
        });

        
        
        var StartTurning = true;

        //Play and Pause Button
        setInterval(function() {
            if (StartTurning) {
              
                ImageCounter++;
            
                //Reset at end of loop.
                if (ImageCounter > imagesArray.length - 1) {
                    ImageCounter = 0;
                }

                //Always update the image.
                $('.ImageDisplay').css({
                    'background-image': 'url(' + imagesArray[ImageCounter] + ')'
                });
                
            }
        }, 100);

        // Code to handle the pause button
        $(".PlayNStopButton").click(function(ffe) {
            StartTurning = !StartTurning;
        });
                  
                  
        
        
        
        //Turn frame forward
        $(".ForwardButton").click(function() {
            StartTurning = false;
            ImageCounter++;
            
            //Reset at end of loop.
            if (ImageCounter > imagesArray.length - 1) {
                ImageCounter = 0;
            }
            
            //Always update the image.
            $('.ImageDisplay').css({
                'background-image': 'url(' + imagesArray[ImageCounter] + ')'
            });

        });
```

```css
.container {
            padding-right: 15px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .container {
                width: 750px;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            .container {
                width: 970px;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
            .container {
                width: 1170px;
            }
        }



        .ImageBox {
            border: silver 1px solid;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .ImageDisplay {
            margin: 25px;
            background-image: url('https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2017/02/01__12_52_27/lamborginhi1.jpgD2F77AE0-1DB0-4FC7-B143-2D141E9ADD45Original-1.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
            background-position: center;
            height: 35vw;
        }


        .ControlBar {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #1F2326;
            padding-top: 25px;
            text-align: center;

        }


        .PreviousButton {
            background-color: white;

            width: 70px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .PreviousButton:hover {
            background-color: #F28C09;
        }

        .PlayNStopButton {
            background-color: white;

            width: 70px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .PlayNStopButton:hover {
            background-color: #F28C09;
        }

        .ForwardButton {
            background-color: white;

            width: 70px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .ForwardButton:hover {
            background-color: #F28C09;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="ImageBox">
            <div class="ImageDisplay">

            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="ControlBar">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="PreviousButton">


                    <svg width="35px" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 30.853 20.892" enable-background="new 0 0 30.853 20.892" xml:space="preserve">
                        <g>
                            <path fill="#1F2326" d="M29.181,0.146c-2.695,1.558-5.393,3.113-8.088,4.671c-0.9,0.521-1.803,1.039-2.701,1.56
                                c0-1.756,0-3.514,0-5.271c0-0.845-0.943-1.379-1.672-0.959C11.328,3.26,5.933,6.375,0.541,9.487c-0.721,0.415-0.721,1.503,0,1.918
                                c5.393,3.112,10.787,6.228,16.18,9.341c0.729,0.42,1.672-0.115,1.672-0.959c0-1.759,0-3.516,0-5.271
                                c3.598,2.077,7.191,4.153,10.789,6.23c0.729,0.42,1.672-0.115,1.672-0.959c0-6.228,0-12.454,0-18.682
                                C30.853,0.261,29.91-0.273,29.181,0.146z"/>
                        </g>
                    </svg>

                    <!-- <img src="Images/Controls/PreviousButton.png"> -->

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="PlayNStopButton">

                    <svg width="30px" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 24.404 21.643" enable-background="new 0 0 24.404 21.643" xml:space="preserve">
                        <g>
                            <g>
                                <path fill="#1F2326" d="M23.881,9.862C18.488,6.75,13.094,3.635,7.701,0.521C6.973,0.102,6.029,0.636,6.029,1.48
                                    c0,6.228,0,12.454,0,18.682c0,0.844,0.943,1.379,1.672,0.959c5.393-3.113,10.787-6.229,16.18-9.341
                                    c0.408-0.236,0.543-0.601,0.521-0.959C24.424,10.463,24.289,10.099,23.881,9.862z"/>
                                <path fill="#1F2326" d="M1.602,0H1.48C0.664,0,0,0.662,0,1.48v18.682c0,0.818,0.664,1.48,1.48,1.48h0.121
                                    c0.818,0,1.481-0.662,1.481-1.48V1.48C3.083,0.662,2.42,0,1.602,0z"/>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>

                    <!-- <img src="Images/Controls/PlayNStopButton.png"> -->

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="ForwardButton">
                    <svg width="35px" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 30.853 20.893" enable-background="new 0 0 30.853 20.893" xml:space="preserve">
                        <g>
                            <path fill="#1F2326" d="M1.672,0.146C4.367,1.704,7.064,3.26,9.76,4.817c0.9,0.521,1.803,1.039,2.701,1.56c0-1.756,0-3.514,0-5.271
                                c0-0.845,0.943-1.379,1.672-0.959c5.393,3.113,10.787,6.229,16.18,9.341c0.721,0.415,0.721,1.503,0,1.918
                                c-5.393,3.112-10.787,6.228-16.18,9.341c-0.729,0.42-1.672-0.115-1.672-0.959c0-1.759,0-3.516,0-5.271
                                c-3.598,2.077-7.191,4.153-10.789,6.23C0.943,21.166,0,20.631,0,19.787C0,13.56,0,7.333,0,1.105C0,0.261,0.943-0.273,1.672,0.146z"
                                />
                        </g>
                    </svg>

                    <!-- <img src="Images/Controls/ForwardButton.png"> -->
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you include two JQuery libraries?

Comment: @mscdeveloper, I think it was a copy paste error. nothing to do with the issue

Comment: Use two/multiple elements positioned on top of each other, and either use `display` for a hard switch, or `opacity` for a fade-over effect ...?

Comment: One common trick is to pre load all the images into invisible img tags or similar.  That way when you switch your url to a new image it’s already loaded.

Comment: I'd suggest to controll the display property and load all the images in the DOM. When the DOM is loaded rotate through them.

Comment: preload images or create a big sprite sheet. These are two options you can try.

Comment: It actually flickers even after the images are loaded. You need a very fast computer.

Comment: @karthick Thanks for the sprite sheet suggestion! I haven't though about it and I think i'll use that since it'll only have to create one image containing each sprites.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a video, host it on youtube and use this code: https://codepen.io/ccrch/pen/GgPLVW/

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/player_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var tv,
    playerDefaults = {autoplay: 0, autohide: 1, modestbranding: 0, rel: 0, showinfo: 0, controls: 0, disablekb: 1, enablejsapi: 0, iv_load_policy: 3};
var vid = [
        {'videoId': '2b5QNj-BVhs', 'startSeconds': 515, 'endSeconds': 690, 'suggestedQuality': 'hd720'},
        {'videoId': '9ge5PzHSS0Y', 'startSeconds': 465, 'endSeconds': 657, 'suggestedQuality': 'hd720'},
        {'videoId': 'OWsCt7B-KWs', 'startSeconds': 0, 'endSeconds': 240, 'suggestedQuality': 'hd720'},
        {'videoId': 'qMR-mPlyduE', 'startSeconds': 19, 'endSeconds': 241, 'suggestedQuality': 'hd720'}
    ],
    randomVid = Math.floor(Math.random() * vid.length),
currVid = randomVid;

$('.hi em:last-of-type').html(vid.length);

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady(){
  tv = new YT.Player('tv', {events: {'onReady': onPlayerReady, 'onStateChange':         onPlayerStateChange}, playerVars: playerDefaults});
}

function onPlayerReady(){
  tv.loadVideoById(vid[currVid]);
  tv.mute();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(e) {
  if (e.data === 1){
$('#tv').addClass('active');
$('.hi em:nth-of-type(2)').html(currVid + 1);
  } else if (e.data === 2){
$('#tv').removeClass('active');
if(currVid === vid.length - 1){
  currVid = 0;
} else {
  currVid++;  
}
tv.loadVideoById(vid[currVid]);
tv.seekTo(vid[currVid].startSeconds);
  }
}

function vidRescale(){

var w = $(window).width()+200,
h = $(window).height()+200;

if (w/h > 16/9){
tv.setSize(w, w/16*9);
$('.tv .screen').css({'left': '0px'});
  } else {
tv.setSize(h/9*16, h);
$('.tv .screen').css({'left': -($('.tv .screen').outerWidth()-w)/2});
  }
}

$(window).on('load resize', function(){
  vidRescale();
});

$('.hi span:first-of-type').on('click', function(){
$('#tv').toggleClass('mute');
$('.hi em:first-of-type').toggleClass('hidden');
  if($('#tv').hasClass('mute')){
tv.mute();
  } else {
tv.unMute();
}
});

$('.hi span:last-of-type').on('click', function(){
  $('.hi em:nth-of-type(2)').html('~');
  tv.pauseVideo();
});
```